# Refresh an iframe without losing it's text/flickering

Tags: php, iframe, refresh, flicker

I run a radio website, and I am trying to make it so that the content (radio info) refreshes automatically.

Currently it is very ugly at refreshing.

I want it to keep the content of the iframe of the radio info until after it is done refreshing.

Here is my code:
PHP for the content with the iframe: http://pastebin.com/fwBjMEUs

PHP for the Radio Info that is to be refreshed: http://pastebin.com/XyfhG8Kn

Comment: don't use iframes, there are better alternatives.

Comment: How exactly would I add that? I don't know the better alternatives.

Comment: I've edited my answer, so it's pretty much a copy and paste job for you. Let me know if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much better off using AJAX for this. This uses a div instead of an iFrame as a container. Just make sure the PHP file only outputs the HTML you want inside the div and then add this script to the page you want to display it on:

```
<script>
function refreshinfo(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("currentinfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.x86cam.com/wp-content/plugins/radio-info.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval(refreshinfo, 20000); /*How often to refresh in ms; currently 20 secs */
</script>
```

Then replace your iframe with `<div id="currentinfo"></div>` and you should be all set!

EDIT:
I've checked the php page that you pull the information, and all you need to do is remove the `<centre>` and `</centre>` tags from it i think, but it may work left in!

Comment: Hey, I just put it in, but it doesn't show up, then 20 seconds later, it does. Help?

Comment: I do apologize! Change setTimeout to setInterval, that should sort it :) I'll edit my answer

Comment: Since it's a radio station, 20 secs may also be a long time to wait for a refresh, 5 seconds (5000 ms) may be a bit more appropriate, but that's just a suggestion :)

Comment: Also I'm abroad right now, so I may be a bit slower to reply if that hasn't fixed your problem! But I've got the WiFi from the hotel across the road, so I'll try to keep an eye on stack! ;D

Comment: Would be nice of you to accept my answer if it's worked, or if it hasn't let me know and I'll try and help sort it!